# What are mechanical requirements for flying over water?

Tags: aircraft-design, regulations, icao, icao-sarps

What are the mechanical requirements to fly over a large water body? Are multiple engines required? Do the engine/s need to be a certain kind (turbofan, turboprop, piston)?

Comment: Are you asking from a commercial operations standpoint, or private? Are you wondering about equipment requirements? I'm not sure what "mechanical" requirements are. How long would they be over water? How far offshore are they travelling?

Comment: The mechanical requirements are the same as for flying over land - if it flies, it doesn't matter what's down below.  Single-engine prop planes regularly cross the Atlantic (see ferry flights), and have done so since Lindberg. Perhaps you are asking about regulatory requirements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Private operations - no requirements. Single-engine is legal, you can argue as to the safety.

Commercial operations...
Single-engine: within gliding distance of the land.
Twin-engines: always within 60 minutes of the land... unless specially approved airplane and operator, and airplane maintained according to much higher specs - this is ETOPS.
More-than-two engines: no problem.